# задача с NULL в C++

Tags: c++

помогите разобраться , нужно написать программу решающее уравнение `(a+b-c)`, но нужно сделать так чтобы если какое либо поле было не заполнено программа выдавала ошибку с просьбой заполнить это поле . Проблема в том когда прописываешь

```
if (a==NULL)
{
    cout<<"EROR";
}
else if (b==NULL)
{
    cout<<"EROR";
}  else if (c==NULL)
{
    cout<<"EROR";
}
```

сам `NULL` выбивается только в две какие нибудь строки а к третьей строки приписывает какой то мусор (-4450001) , помогие написать программу пожалуйста

Comment: забыл написать в скобочках написано {cout<<"EROR";}

Comment: Скорее всего у вас не инициализированы пнеременные, соответственно там может лежать мусор.

Comment: Брр... Приведите [минимальный компилируемый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pls... Непонятно что-то...

Comment: Вопрос сформулирован бессмысленно. Что такое `a`, `b` и `c` и чего это вдруг вы взялись сравнивать их с `NULL`? `NULL` в С++ используется только с указателями. Ваши `a`, `b` и `c` - это указатели? Судя по условию, нет. При  чем здесь тогда вообще `NULL`?

Comment: Это вам не JS какой-нибудь, где любая переменная может быть `null`. :)

Comment: используйте 0 вместо NULL если у вас там переменные, переменные не могут быть NULL их значение по умолчанию - 0

Comment: a , b и с переменные int  . им надо задать значение чтобы пример решался . и чтобы если три поля не заполнены выдавало ошибку с просьбой заполнить это поле. кто подскажет как грамотно это сделать? даже если сделать указатель к примеру n1=NULL и присвоит n1 всем переменым то все равно выбирается только два из них

Comment: `a+b-c`  - это не уравнение.  Это разность между суммой чисел `a` и `b` и числом `c`. Уравнением это станет, когда вы напишите чему это выражение должно быть равно. Например: `a+b-c=100500`